# Eye-Tracking library in C#, C/C++ or Objective-C

Tags: c#, c++, c, open-source, eye-tracking

Anyone know of an eye-tracking library for C#, C/C++ or Objective-C? Open-source is preferable. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this with just a webcam? Or something more complicated like IR reflection off the retina?

Answer (score 9):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) could probably do it. It has the ability to perform face recognition, so eye tracking might be a subset of that.

Comment: Errr, why the downvote!  He's 100% right, OpenCV provides the base functionality to creating eye tracking.  Buy the book and go through it, it contains that specific example!

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a page full of eye-tracking resources](http://www.cogain.org/eyetrackers/low-cost-eye-trackers), many of them open-source.

Comment: 404. is there a buckup for the link?

Comment: It looks like the information has since been moved to this wiki page: http://www.cogain.org/wiki/Eye_Trackers#Open_source_gaze_tracking_and_freeware_eye_tracking

Comment: Now the wiki page is also showing up as a 404!

Comment: The wiki page appears to have a new URL: http://wiki.cogain.org/index.php/Eye_Trackers